# How to install github package in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, github, package, github-pages, laravel-7

I am new in **laravel 7**. i want ask how to install github package into my laravel project.
(https://github.com/lomotech/jajahan) this package i want to install to my laravel but not instruction in this package.

Answer (score 1):

If a package is missing a `composer.json`, you can add the following to your project's `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "lomotech/jajahan",
      "version": "v2.2018.01",
      "source": {
        "url": "https://github.com/lomotech/jajahan",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "master"
      }
    }
  }
],
"require": {
  "lomotech/jajahan": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Lomotech\\Jajahan\\": "vendor/lomotech/jajahan/"
    }
},
```

The `autoload` entry allows composer to generate the vendor classmaps so you can use the package in your code by:

```
use Lomotech\Jajahan\SomeClassFile;
```

Finally, run `composer install/update`.

Comment: Wow didn't know this. Thanks for sharing

Comment: sorry for another question. how to use the file in that package in my laravel project

Comment: @IkmalMohd Not a problem, I've updated the answer to show how to add an `autoload` entry to your `composer.json`.